How to serve static files from a Spring component project in a JAR, within a main project that depends on it?
I have two projects in Spring. One is a library of reusable components, which has static files (CSS, JS). The other project is the main application, where I need to serve these static files. By "serve", I mean being able to access the JS files from the components project. I've packaged them into a JAR file, but when I try to use the component "control-tipos.js", the path is not being resolved.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried using dependencies, and it can detect the classes but not the static files (JS, CSS).

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Please also add, how you are using the JS (e.g. post the annotation with the path you are using); also have you configured/restricted, the packages vaadin is allowed to visit?

Also when you replace the images, make sure, that you give the error there some context. It looks like it's an error you get either from prod or dev build from vaadin and if this is indeed the case, then phrasing the question like you want to "serve static files" will attract the wrong kinds of answers (the single files are served by themself at best in the dev-server; they are otherwise compiled into a bundle)

If you already provided the right dependency to ensure communication between the two project then make sure to (mvn clean install) and then check if your files are included in (BOOT-INF/classes/static) if so ,
try calling your html page ofcourse dont forget to add your javascript file
<script src="/js/script.js"></script> 

to your html file.
please note sometimes spring boot doesn't recognise the static folder so make sure to create the folder and files structure correctly.
you can read about it here : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources

Based on your screenshot I'm assuming you're using the Vaadin Framework.
Location of Files in Addon Project:
The "addon" project must have its static files placed in the correct directory (you've already done this correctly). In the "addon" project, the resources should be placed in:
src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend
Accessing Files in Main Project:
In the main project, accessing the files from your addon project's jar will differ depending on where you are accessing them (from your frontend files or your Java files).
From a Frontend View:
Replace META-INF/resources/frontend with Frontend/generated/jar-resources/. So the path to your control-tipos.js file would be Frontend/generated/jar-resources/componentes/controltipos/control-tipos.js.
Example:
// import your control-tipos file from a frontend view 
// for example: src/main/frontend/views/main-view.tsx

import "Frontend/generated/jar-resources/componentes/controltipos/control-tipos.js";
// or
import {controlComponent} from "Frontend/generated/jar-resources/componentes/controltipos/control-tipos.js";


export default function MainView() {
  ....
}

From a Java View:
Replace META-INF/resources/frontend with ./. So the path to your control-tipos.js file would be ./componentes/controltipos/control-tipos.js.
Example:
@JsModule("./componentes/controltipos/control-tipos.js")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
  ...
}

You can refer to the documentation for loading resources to understand the correct paths to use for the resources: Loading Resources.
